# What's wrong with Android's Random.nextInt(2^N)?

Tags: java, android, random

I executed the following code several times by clicking the button:

```
int UP = 4;
Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "random", new Random().nextInt(UP) + " " 
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
                               + new Random().nextInt(UP) + " "
 );
```

And I was very surprised of getting this in the log:

```
04-07 21:26:36.659: D/random(15640): 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
04-07 21:26:37.059: D/random(15640): 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
04-07 21:26:37.429: D/random(15640): 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
04-07 21:26:37.789: D/random(15640): 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
04-07 21:26:38.119: D/random(15640): 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
04-07 21:26:38.429: D/random(15640): 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
04-07 21:26:38.739: D/random(15640): 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
04-07 21:26:39.019: D/random(15640): 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
04-07 21:26:39.319: D/random(15640): 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 
04-07 21:26:39.599: D/random(15640): 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

--for sure, these sequences are absolutely non-random.

**I know, that I should create one instance of `Random` object and call its `nexInt()` as many times as I need.** But Java changes static seed number every time new Random instance is created by `Random()` constructor:

```
public Random() { 
    this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); 
}
private static volatile long seedUniquifier = 8682522807148012L;
```

so produced sequences should be random independently on that whether we use one object or every time the new one. But for some reason they are not.

I decided to continue my research, calling `nextInt()` with different arguments. And what I saw next, surprised me much more. I noticed that every time I choose `UP` constant *to be power of 2*, result of `new Random().nextInt(UP)` remains absolutely non-random, but when I choose *different number*, everything is quite OK.

UP = 8:

```
04-07 21:43:47.169: D/random(15789): 5 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 
04-07 21:43:47.809: D/random(15789): 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
04-07 21:43:48.249: D/random(15789): 6 7 7 7 7 6 6 6 
04-07 21:43:48.619: D/random(15789): 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
04-07 21:43:48.999: D/random(15789): 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 4 
04-07 21:43:49.399: D/random(15789): 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

UP = 32:

```
04-07 21:45:27.979: D/random(15888): 16 15 15 14 15 15 15 24 
04-07 21:45:28.329: D/random(15888): 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 21 
04-07 21:45:28.549: D/random(15888): 22 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 
04-07 21:45:28.849: D/random(15888): 31 31 31 31 31 31 29 29 
04-07 21:45:29.329: D/random(15888): 27 28 28 28 26 26 26 26
```

But for UP = 10 result looks random, doesn't it? --

```
04-07 21:47:02.189: D/random(15983): 8 4 1 9 6 6 4 2 
04-07 21:47:02.639: D/random(15983): 7 5 3 0 7 5 2 0 
04-07 21:47:02.999: D/random(15983): 3 9 6 4 1 8 6 3 
04-07 21:47:03.379: D/random(15983): 5 4 1 8 6 3 0 8 
04-07 21:47:03.669: D/random(15983): 5 1 8 6 3 3 1 8 
04-07 21:47:03.989: D/random(15983): 3 3 1 4 1 8 6 3 
04-07 21:47:04.269: D/random(15983): 6 6 3 1 8 5 3 0
```

So I have only one question: anyone knows what's happening and why? Why results obtained by `nextInt(2^N)` are non-random while results obtained with any other argument are quite good?

==================================

**Update.** Guys in comments say that on desktop JVM results are random independently on number passed as `nextInt()` argument. So is described behavior specific only to Android?

**Update 2.** The answer marked as a best for this question and, especially, discussion below it give quite clear explanation of what happens.

Comment: "But Java changes static seeding number every time new Random instance is created by Random() constructor" This seems to be contradicted by your data.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added a piece of source code which shows that it really does... I have no idea why such happens when 2^N is put on nextInt().. for other numbers everything looks good.

Comment: Random uses two seeds if I remember correctly. One is a constant seed across all instances, and the other is an `AtomicLong` of the time when it was initiated

Comment: Cannot reproduce on desktop JVM, with any `UP` value.

Comment: @Rogue it uses `static long seedUniquifier` which is incremented every time new `Random` instance is created. So even if we suppose that current time doesn't change, whole seed value should change.

Comment: @Salauyou what environment are you running this on ? I run your code and have expected pseudo-random distribution for UP various values, including 4,8,32, etc

Comment: @kiruwka Dalvik VM (Android 4.0)

Comment: @Geobits I ran it on Android 4.0 and 4.1.2

Comment: creating several Random instances in a row is likely to result is identical seeds.

Comment: @njzk2 why this doesn't effect when calling nextInt() with argument different from 2^N?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java documentation on `nextInt()`:

> public int nextInt(int n) Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly
>   distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value
>   (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence. The
>   general contract of nextInt is that one int value in the specified
>   range is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All n possible int
>   values are produced with (approximately) equal probability. The method
>   nextInt(int n) is implemented by class Random as if by:

```
 public int nextInt(int n) {
   if (n <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

   *if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
     return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);*

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % n;
   } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

Note the specific case for when n is a power of 2. Regardless of the n you pass into `nextInt`, the function `next` is called with the same input bits, and the return statement is simply n times that, so any time you're issuing a power of 2 request, it's going to come back very deterministic.

Comment: I tried to use one instance of Random() and generate nextInt(2^N) many times--everything was good. There is something wrong with initial seed value which somehow interact with this 'special case'.

Comment: That's because after you call it the first time, it's going to return a value that's not a power of 2, which then results in the 'normal' path being taken in nextInt(), so that the series will randomize. As it is, you're calling nextInt repeatedly with '4' and only one time, so that it will always just return (4*next(31))>>31).

Comment: but I still don't understand what happens in initialization. Every time new Random object is created, it changes its seed value. So what wrong with it? Or it just is not changed correctly (for example, because of non-atomic nature of long)?..

Comment: sorry, but this explanation does not look convincing so far. if you look at implementation of `next(int bits)` you'll see that it is based on current seed, and not only input. Besides, I can't reproduce strange results so far on desktop. Gotta try with android

Comment: There's no formal definition really stated anywhere in the documentation, but the seed value generated in the constructor is almost certainly based on system time (as most pseudo-random generators are). Since you are rapidly declaring multiple constructions, the seed value for each will either have largely matching higher order bits, or be completely matching. On top of that, the next() function lops off the low-order bits, so that if high-order bits are matching, the seed will become identical. Because of that, next() will return the same value, despite the constructor statement.

Comment: @kiruwka so what's your result on Android?

Comment: @Salauyou well, doing some debugging I discovered several things. 1) [pretty obvious], if you introduce some artificial sleeps between your Random() constructors you'll get much more random results, meaning what you get is partially due to "bad" seeding and partially because of what `SeaNick` explained for 2^N. 2)Android source for Random.java (seeding in construction and `next`) is very different from `jdk` implemenation as well it differs between android versions drastically. For example, in my 4.2.2, `Random()` constructor seeds with time in milliseconds, and not in nanoseconds !!!

Comment: @kiruwka wow! about ms instead of ns--that's something really surprising. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SeaNick +1. I agree with you that for 2^N you get results much more dependant on the seed(because `next` is only called once in that case), and since we have very "close" seeds between instances close in time it makes results look much less random.

Comment: From Android 4.2.2: `public Random(){setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis() + System.identityHashCode(this));}`